# What is the meaning of the series?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0379786/synopsis)

> Two faces familiar from the series are no longer aboard, but we meet
>   them later: the "companion"

what does series mean & aboard on what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Series* refers to *television series*

> [tv series](http://www.yourdictionary.com/tv-series)
>   A group of episodes of a television program broadcast in regular intervals with a long break between each group, usually with one year between the beginning of each.

Specifically, it refers to the [*Firefly*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303461/) tv series.

> [aboard](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aboard)
>   : on, onto, or within a train, a ship, an airplane, etc.

So the two people are no longer riding in the ship. They were aboard the spaceship *Serenity*.